# return format color if multiple values are true

Tags: microsoft-excel

I tried different formulas in conditioning formatting, but none seems to work. Can someone please help me with the following:

I need cell `J2` to turn **red** if `I2` show **completed**, but `F2` is **smaller** than `G2`.

Here my last try:

```
=If((G2="completed"),if(F2<G2))=TRUE,FALSE
```

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Translate the human word "but" by the computer/human word "and": I2 show completed, AND F2 < G2. More elaborated: See Mayukh's answer.

Comment: @Dominique sir, correct OP already have their answer, but the construction of the formula is not following the basic principle of `IF()` and `AND()` I completely agree with you!

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need to do:

[image]

---

• Formula in Conditional Formatting:

```
=(I2="COMPLETED")*(F2<G2)
```

---

**Note:** The `*` operator works as an `AND()` function here. Also you formula is not working because it is not following the principle syntax of `IF()` function, however, you don't need an `IF()`, a quick fix to your original formula will be:

```
=AND(I2="COMPLETED",F2<G2)
```

---

BTW you can read more on `IF()` function and `AND()` function from `MSFT` Documentations [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9). That will help you understand more and there are few examples which may give you more insights.

---

Comment: WOW! thank you so much. this is even better than I imagine. Thanks for the links. I will read up some more.

Comment: @JOSEPH you may accept the answer by ticking checkmark beside it so it helps someone in the future.